# Is there an `id` of `prism' id Just`?

Tags: haskell, haskell-optics

I have a function called:

```hs
mapRouteEncoder ::
  Prism' FilePath FilePath ->
  Prism' r1 r2 ->
  (b -> a) ->
  RouteEncoder a r1 ->
  RouteEncoder b r2
```

This function is often used by specifying "identity" prisms (if we can call it that) in the first two arguments because only the 3rd function is specified, viz.:

```hs
    stringRouteEncoder
      & mapRouteEncoder (prism' id Just) (prism' id Just) changeModel
```

I use [`optics-core`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/optics-core-0.4/docs/Optics-Prism.html#t:Prism), and is there anything in that library to replace `prism' id Just` something more idiomatic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the idioms for that package, but I'd be tempted to use `castOptic equality` to turn the identity `Iso` into a `Prism`. That seems to get the idea across pretty well. However, I would expect that in most contexts you wouldn't actually *need* to convert it to a `Prism`; you can presumably use polymorphic functions (like `preview` and `review`) that will accept an `Iso` as well as a `Prism`.

In your case, I suspect the right approach would be to write something like

```
mapRouteEncoder ::
  ( p1 `Is` A_Prism
  , p2 `Is` A_Prism) =>
  Optic' p1 ixy1 FilePath FilePath ->
  Optic' p2 ixy2 r1 r2 ->
  (b -> a) ->
  RouteEncoder a r1 ->
  RouteEncoder b r2
```

Comment: Nice, this is [indeed an improvement](https://github.com/srid/ema/pull/81/commits/1fe00e64f03b2bdae7b99f65ee593ed66ab10116)

Comment: And it allows me to use other values like `coercedTo`, which is pretty great.

Comment: Glad I could help!